# Mini Cart Update issue

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax, mini-cart

I am facing **mini cart** update issue - to replicate the issue you need to browse the site and add a product to the cart - then **continue shopping**. If you press **checkout** (instead of continue shopping) the cart shows **right qty**. If you **continue to shop** (though the cart is updated, but the mini cart shows 0 products in  cart) If we browse through any other product on the website the cart starts showing the right **qty**.

**I am not sure what is this issue exactly.**

Comment: Welcome to magento community @akshi.

Comment: Did you add product using ajax ?

Comment: thanks @RohanHapani I think so, add to cart gives me two option to continue shop or to proceed to checkout. If I continue to shop i get this issue